# Gatling - How to import objects from packages

Tags: scala, gatling

I wish to have a file containing util variables to reuse inside my simulations classes but I'm getting these errors:

```
18:15:22.702 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - /app/simulations/keyword_search/test.scala:9:20: object Args is not a member of package simulations
import simulations.Args._
                   ^
18:15:22.711 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - /app/simulations/keyword_search/test.scala:12:13: not found: value name
    println(name)
            ^
18:15:22.726 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - two errors found
18:15:22.740 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation crashed
```

I have the following scenario:

**Project path:**

```
simulations/
--keyword_search/
----test.scala
--args.scala
```

**`simulations/args.scala`** file:

```scala
package simulations

object Args {
  val name = "bla"
}
```

**`simulations/keyword_search/test.scala`** file:

```scala
package simulations.keyword_search

import simulations.Args._

class Test extends Simulation {
  print(name)
}
```

I'm running `gatling` with following script:

```sh
gatling -sf /app/simulations/keyword_search -s simulations.keyword_search.Test
```

Is this correct ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gatling is not aware of `args.scala`, since the file is outside the directory specified as simulations folder `-sf`.
Please run your Gatling simulation using `/app/simulations` as a simulations folder:

```
gatling -sf /app/simulations -s simulations.keyword_search.Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import package as:

```
import users._  // import everything from the users package
import users.User  // import the class User
import users.{User, UserPreferences}  // Only imports selected members
import users.{UserPreferences => UPrefs}  // import and rename for convenience
```